# Smallest Length array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I wanted to create a method that from two given arrays, he outputs the one with the smallest length but the method always asks for a return outside the if statements

```java
public static int[][] SmallestArray(int[][] A, int[][] B){
    if(A.length < B.length){
        if(A[0].length <B[0].length)
            return A;
    }
    else if(B.length < A.length){
        if(B[0].length <A[0].length)
            return B;
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot B.length == A.length case

Comment: You don't cover all execution paths. All non void methods require a path to a return statement

Comment: That's because there are still cases left where none of the conditions are true. You then end up in a branch that is not covered, but the method still has to return something. For example: what happens when ``A`` and ``B`` have the same length?

Comment: For example, what if `A[0] > B[0]` in the first condition? Also, you aren't guaranteed to get a square array, so `A[1]` could be longer than `A[0]`

Comment: I was told A[0].length returns the nr of colums in the array

Comment: Some questions:  What if either A or B are null? What if A and B are the same length? What if either A or B are length 0? What if A.length>B.length but A[0].length>=B[0].length? What if B.length>A.length but B[0].length>=A[0].length?

Answer (score 0):

There are uncovered paths in your code. That means that there are cases where the execution of your method finishes without having encountered a `return` statement. But since you declared that your method returns and `int[][]`, that has to be returned somewhere.

Here are the paths without a return statement:

```
public static int[][] SmallestArray(int[][] A, int[][] B){
    if(A.length < B.length){
        if(A[0].length <B[0].length){
            return A;
        }
        //possibly here
    }
    else if(B.length < A.length){
        if(B[0].length <A[0].length){
            return B;
        }
        //possibly here
    }
    //definitely here!
    //in this case A and B have the same length.
    //You have return an int[][], which one will it be?
}
```

Comment: No, they're only possibly missing returns. It might be OK to fall through and handle all other cases in the same way.

Comment: @cricket_007 You don't need the ``possibly``s. The ``definitely`` one will be executed as a fallback for all those cases.

Comment: Well, for compiling, yes, that makes sense. For the logic in the code, I'd say the OP should include those returns, though

Answer (score 0):

Some cases are not covered by your code.

For example: (B.length == A.length) is not managed.

You have to put some else statements.

```
public static int[][] SmallestArray(int[][] A, int[][] B){
    if(A.length < B.length){
        if(A[0].length <B[0].length){
            return A;
         } else {
            //  uncovered case
         }
    }
    else if(B.length < A.length){
        if(B[0].length <A[0].length){
            return B;
         } else {
            //  uncovered case
         }
    }
    else {
       //  uncovered case
    }
}
```

A good practice is to have only one return statement at the end of your method.

```
public static int[][] SmallestArray(int[][] A, int[][] B){

    int[][] result = null ;
    // do the job
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is practically a duplicate of the other answer

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the `if else` paradigm.

Top level `if else` should return the value which is not in your case. You are returning value from a sub condition(one more if condition) inside the your top level condition, and compiler is expecting a return type either from top level condition or at method end.

you can achieve it in either ways:

```
1.)

    public static int[][] SmallestArray(int[][] A, int[][] B){
        if(A.length < B.length){
            if(A[0].length < B[0].length)
                return A;
        }
        else if(B.length < A.length){
            if(B[0].length < A[0].length) 
                return B;
        }
        return null;

    }

2.)

    public static int[][] SmallestArray(int[][] A, int[][] B){
        if(A.length < B.length){
            if(A[0].length < B[0].length)
                return A;
            return B; // return from top level if
        }
        else if(B.length < A.length){
            if(B[0].length < A[0].length) 
                return B;
            return A; // return from top level else
        }
        return null;

    }
```